# inserting text in last cell after row of data

Tags: vba, excel

I have done a comparison of 2 sheets which highlights differences.  In my vb/macro code I am copying missing ID's to a new sheet.

Here is a snippet of the code:

```
If IsError(int_row_id) Then
        'ID missing 
        id.EntireRow.Copy
        missing.PasteSpecial xlPasteValuesAndNumberFormats
        Application.CutCopyMode = False
        Set missing = missing.Offset(RowOffset:=1)
```

So if the ID is missing then copy that entire row and paste this into sheet missing. What I want to do is at the end of this row of data in the next cell after the data has been pasted add the phrase "Missing from New Data"

Any advice will be appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
If IsError(int_row_id) Then
   With Sheets("missing")
        last_row = .Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
        id.EntireRow.Copy Destination:=.Range("A"&last_row+1)
        last_column = .Cells(last_row+1, .Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
        .Cells(last_row+1, last_column+1) = "Missing from New Data"
   End With
```